# Face Detection with "Beyond Face Reality" SDK, copy to new canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, face-detection

I am looking for someone advanced in the "Beyond Face Reality" SDK. A great and free face tracking framework.

https://www.beyond-reality-face.com/overview

We are using the SDK for a school project. We are using the CandideFaceTracking option which reveals a perfect picture of the face.

Our project is available on

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kxfh6j5j4k7z780/gezichtherkenning.zip?dl=0

We want to cut out the the outer lines of the face, and place the face on a new canvas.

We are not as experienced in code as most people around because we have a media design education.

We have found the data by using:

```
_this._brfManager.faceShape.candideShapeVertices
```

You will find this line in the file "exampleBase.js" on line 398.

But we are stuck for a few days now. Would be great to receive help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please have a look at [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how you could improve your question. Also please provide code snippets and show us what you've tried already.

Comment: thanks for you answer. I tried converting the polygon data with the following stack overflow example : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29581036/html-5-canvas-copying-pixel-data-within-a-polygon)

Comment: That's great, but please include the relevant code itself in your question (so, edit your question). Try and make it as easy as possible for us to detect the problem. Having to download, unzip, compile, and then look through code via dropbox is not an easy way.